# Don't know why `asyncio.Lock` is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, discord, discord.py

So what this does is that whenever someone types the command `!test` into the chatroom channel, it prints out the appropriate below strings into the chat channel. However, I want the command to be used only once at a time, so I want to lock the command until it is finished:

```
import discord, asyncio, time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    lock = Lock() # define Lock
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!test") and not lock.locked():
        lock.acquire() # Lock the !test command so it can't be used now
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test1rgews')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test2thewf')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test3rhtvw')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test4trjyr')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test5dmuye')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        lock.release() # Unlock the !test command now

client.run('clienttokenhere')
```

But I get an error that says `NameError: name 'Lock' is not defined`, even though I did define it as `lock = Lock()`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to import modules to use names from them. You must either use `asyncio.Lock` or `from asyncio import Lock`.